# how to upload files to s3 through a static site hosted on EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cognito

I am trying to host a **static website on an EC2 instance** which takes file as an input from the user and stores it in a bucket in S3.
How can I achieve it ? Can anybody help me with the steps?

Comment: Could you provide some more details on this such as language, or examples of what you have done already? :)

Comment: @ChrisWilliams is it possible to upload a file to S3 from a static website hosted on Ec2 ??

Comment: Of course this is possible :), do you perhaps have any experience with specific web technologies already?

Comment: yes I am familiar with HTML and css

Comment: @ChrisWilliams I was successfully able to host an angular app on S3 . Can I do the same on EC2 ? Can you share a link ?

Comment: Here's a tutorial: https://medium.com/@sandeeptengale/deploy-angular-app-on-aws-ec2-instance-20749f17b33e :)

Comment: Thanks a ton @ChrisWilliams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is of course popular, although you are responsible for installing any software on the instance for hosting including any necessary web hosting software (such as Nginx).

You have said you're experienced with Angular so feel free to take a look at [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@sandeeptengale/deploy-angular-app-on-aws-ec2-instance-20749f17b33e) which covers the basics.

For the frontend for putting an object you can use the JavaScript SDK using either [putObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property) or [upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property).

For credentials of a frontend only application you would configure a [cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) user pool to generate the temporary credentials and then use them with the SDK.

Comment: Hi , Can you help me .I have completed all the steps given above. I have updated the question as it was closed before

Comment: Is the bucket using versioning?

Comment: No, it isn't using versioning